# How to use ACH payments in North America with stripe payment Intents

Tags: stripe-payments

attempting to use a payment method of a ACH payment...but I can't figure out how to do it. Theoretically the documentation here says I can.

https://stripe.com/payments/payment-methods-guide#for-professional-services

However when I go here:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/create#create_payment_method-type

I see 'card' listed, but I do not see anything related to 'bank' or 'ach' or 'check' so I am confused.

I have no issues following their instructions to manually create a "bank" object programmatically, and then making then making that bank object a "source" as shown here:

```
const bank_submit_object = {
  "object": 'bank_account',
  "country": 'US',
  "currency": 'usd',
  "routing_number": routing_number,
  "account_number": account_number,
  "account_holder_name": account_name,
  "account_holder_type": account_type
}
const bankAccount = await stripe.customers.createSource(
  'customer_id',
  { source: bank_submit_object }
);
```

My problem is sources is listed as an Older api
https://stripe.com/docs/sources

And previously to today (the warnings are gone today for some reason), the documentation would flash a warning saying sources are the old way of doing things and to stop doing it.

So in order to do things the new way, can somebody help suggest how to do ACH payments using payment methods and NOT sources.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not supported by the current public API. For payments using ACH today, you should follow [this guide](https://stripe.com/docs/ach) using the legacy Charges API.

Note the callout at the top mentioning a beta for ACH payments using Payment Intents. If you're interested in that, you should fill out the linked form.

**Edit 2022**: The new Payment Methods & Payment Intents API support for ACH direct debit has since been released. See here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/ach-debit

Comment: The "callout" seems to be gone now, which could mean ACH Debit payments are now out of beta in respect to PaymentMethods (PaymentIntents) Stripe API.

Comment: That's right, I've updated the answer to point to the new docs for ACH debits using Payment Intents and Payment Methods.

Comment: @br
Have been trying this thought i was going crazy, but looks like there is a MAJOR bug in both test mode and

Comment: @brendan-moore
Have been trying this thought i was going crazy, but looks like there is a MAJOR bug in both test mode and live mode. Success url redirection after connecting bank does not work. Thought it was me, but stripe chat support also seeing it...so bug bounty avail? Ironically the hackerone site is comprimised (live hack doesn't allow new registration) so stripe def should figure something else out to report major issues with.